# tabularray: shorten vline

Tags: matrices, tabularray

Is it possible to shorten the vertical line in `tabularray?
I would like to use it for augmented matrices as follows, but I find the line too long:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
M =
\begin{+pmatrix}[vline{Y,Y} = {1,Z}{.1pt}]
123 & 2  & 9    & 3 \\
1   & -3 & -600 & 3 \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of the options `abovepos` and `belowpos`. With value `-1`, "the vline is trimmed by `rowsep`" as stated in the manual. You need to define this separately for the upper and the lower row, however:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
M =
\begin{+pmatrix}[
        vline{Y} = {1}{abovepos = -1}, 
        vline{Y} = {Z}{belowpos = -1}
    ]
123 & 2  & 9    & 3 \\
1   & -3 & -600 & 3 \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to add a third row or even more rows, you would need to additionally define these middle rows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
M =
\begin{+pmatrix}[
        vline{Y} = {1}{abovepos = -1}, 
        vline{Y} = {2-Y}{},
        vline{Y} = {Z}{belowpos = -1}
    ]
123 & 2  & 9    & 3 \\
1   & -3 & -600 & 3 \\
1   & -3 & -600 & 3 \\
1   & -3 & -600 & 3 \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed the line width to the default 0.4 pt, since I think that 0.1 pt is a bit too thin. But feel free to change to `vline{Y} = {1}{0.1pt, abovepos = -1}` or whatever you like.

Answer (score 3):

Between the matrices there is an interesting package called `spalign`. Usage: `\spalignaugmatn [column alignment]{augmented columns}{text}`
produces a matrix with a vertical divider located augmented columns from the right
side of the matrix. The column alignment is interpreted as in `\spalignmat`; the
default is `r`.
The result is fine and it is as `nicematrix` and `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{spalign}


\begin{document}
\[\spalignaugmatn[l]{1}{123 2 9 3;1 -3 -600 3}\]
\[\spalignaugmatn[c]{1}{123 2 9 3;1 -3 -600 3}\]
\[\spalignaugmatn[r]{1}{123 2 9 3;1 -3 -600 3}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]